# How to fetch the filename from CSV and insert it into one of columns of a table

Tags: sql, shell, csv, vertica

Suppose `mt table` name is `Table_1`

Structure of the table is something like:

```
EMP_id, Emp_Name, File_Name_Input_Date (columns)
```

I am loading `Table_1` from a CSV file. The name of this CSV file is `daily_01122014.csv`

I am using vertical copy command to load this table:

```
ex copy Table_1 from '/location/daily_01122014.csv'delimiter ',';
```

It will load the table, but column name `File_Name_Input_Date` will be left blank, and I have to hard code it.

What I want is to write a shell script which will dynamically read file name and load it into `column File_Name`, and also extract date from file name.

i.e:  If file name is `daily_01122014.csv`, then while loading `Table_1` column `File_Name` should be `daily_01122014.csv` and `Input_Date` should be `2014-12-01`. Since I have 50-60 files, I can not do it manually.

Comment: solutions for your request were given !

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is adding this string to the file before you load the data to Vertica 
**See here an example:**

```
[dbadmin@DCXLG001 tmp]$ cat file001.csv
1,Adrian
[dbadmin@DCXLG001 tmp]$ ls -1 file*.csv|xargs -I% sed -i 's/$/,%/' %
[dbadmin@DCXLG001 tmp]$ cat file001.csv
1,Adrian,file001.csv
```

- where i have a file called file*.csv and i add the name of the file to the end of each line in the actual file.
You can do this to any more then one file. 
I would use the operation system resources to do this transformation then trying to create a filler using Vetica's copy command

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`CURRENT_LOAD_SOURCE()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Current_Load/CURRENT_LOAD_SOURCE.htm) inside your `COPY`:

```
COPY t (c1, c2, c3 AS CURRENT_LOAD_SOURCE()) 
FROM '/home/load_file_1' ON exampledb_node02, '/home/load_file_2' ON exampledb_node03 
DELIMITER ',';
```

Alternatively, you can use a [shell script](https://community.vertica.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/COPY-many-flat-files-to-one-table-and-save-the-file-name-to-a/m-p/215559#M5439):

```
#!/bin/bash
for INPUT_FILE in /path/to/file*.dat; do
vsql -c "copy test_file_name_insert
(
input_file_name as '$INPUT_FILE',
id,
name
)
from '/home/test_input_file.txt'
delimiter '|' ;"
done
```

Comment: Sounds like he also wants to parse out the date. Maybe something like `TO_DATE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(CURRENT_LOAD_SOURCE(),'_',2),'.',1),'DDMMYYYY'))` would work.  Not sure, he references one column in part of his question and then two later.

Comment: @woot I think you're out of line sir.

Comment: It's not easy being green, is it, @Kermit ?

Comment: @woot not if you're shopping on woot all day